# How do I update a list item with the outcomes of tasks from it's workflow

Tags: workflow, item

Platform: SharePoint 2013 On-Prem Enterprise.

I have a list (list A) with items.  I start an approval (SP2010 OOTB version) workflow on an item in list A that assigns a number of tasks to various users in a serial fashion through the approval workflow.

How do I update the item in list A with information on those approval workflow tasks such as who it was assigned to, what was the task outcome, what if any comments were entered in the tasks.

I would like to be able to do this in SharePoint 2013 designer.

Answer (score 0):

When a task is assigned, task outcome and task ID can be captured as below:
Then based on task ID, required fields can be captured.

[image]

Comment: Deepmala, thank you for the response.  If I have n number of tasks, how can I updated the results of each task (result of task, comments of task, who performed task, etc) in a column within the item the workflow is being performed on if I don't know ahead of time how many tasks are involved in the workflow?  In other words, how would I append the results of when task 2 is finished after task 1 has been completed or n number of tasks?